# Tkinter radiobutton not working with IntVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to get this code to return the difficulty value by using tkinter radiobuttons. I have a problem that the variable never changes from 0 to the difficulty. When I run this code, my console looks like this:

```
TEXT and VALUE Child's play 0.15
TEXT and VALUE Very Easy 0.3
TEXT and VALUE Easy 0.4
TEXT and VALUE Normal 0.5
TEXT and VALUE Hard 0.6
TEXT and VALUE Very Hard 0.7
TEXT and VALUE Insanely Hard 0.8
TEXT and VALUE Impossible 0.9
```

* I select the "Very Hard" radiobutton and click "OK"*

```
You selected the option 0
```

Here is the full code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import IntVar


difficulty = 0.40

def set_settings():
    print("\n\n\nYou selected the option " + str(var.get()))
    settings.destroy()

settings = tk.Tk()
settings.config(bg = "white")
settings.geometry("+600+400")
settings.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", set_settings)
settings.title('Settings')
settings.resizable(False, False)

MODES = [
            ("Child's play", 0.15),
            ("Very Easy", 0.30),
            ("Easy", 0.40),
            ("Normal", 0.50),
            ("Hard", 0.60),
            ("Very Hard", 0.70),
            ("Insanely Hard", 0.80),
            ("Impossible", 0.90)
        ]

label_1 = tk.Label(settings, font = 'Times 20', text = "Difficulty:", bg = "white")
label_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10)

frame_1 = tk.Frame(settings, bg="white")
frame_1.grid(row = 1, column=2, columnspan = 2)

var = IntVar()
var.set(difficulty)
for text, value in MODES:
    print("TEXT and VALUE", text, value)
    r_button = tk.Radiobutton(frame_1, font="Times 13", bg="white", text = text, variable=var, value=value)
    r_button.pack()

but_one = tk.Button(settings, font = 'Times 12', text = "OK", command = set_settings, bg = "white")
but_one.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

settings.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `MODES` values are floating points below zero. All of those values will get converted to zero as an integer.

Comment: Hey thanks!!! Now I feel really stupid :P